# Which homescreen the user is in

Tags: android, android-widget

Hi I'm trying to develop android home screen widget and can I get which homescreen the user is in.
if user in home page that my widget on , i want to do some changing on widget.

Sorry my poor eng.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are hundreds, perhaps thousands, of home screen implementations.

Not all have to have separate "home pages". None that do have to have an API to let you know what page the user is on and what page your app widget is on.

If you want this functionality, implement your own home screen, or talk to specific home screen authors to see if they are willing to expose such an API to you.